# Why is §5/5 applied when deducing template arguments? Couldn't the rules be different?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T t) {
    std::cout << t << '\n';
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int const*>::value, "T != int const*");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(t), int const*>::value, "decltype(t) != int const*");
}

template<typename T>
void g(T t) {
    std::cout << t << '\n';
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "T != int");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(t), int>::value, "decltype(t) != int");
    t++;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 22;
    int const* px = &x;

    f(px);

    int const& rx = x;
    g(rx);
}
```

The code executes normally. But according to the current rules we get:

- `T == int const*` and `t` has type `int const*` in the instantiation of the template function `f` in the call `f(px)`.
- `T == int` and `t` has type `int` in the instantiation of the template function `g` in the call `g(rx)`.

My first thought for the second deduction would be something symmetrical to the pointer case, i.e., with `T == int const&` and `t` with type `int const&`.

I think I know what's going with the current deduction process executed by the compiler. By §5.5 the reference is dropped in the expression `rx` passed to `g`. That is, the type of `rx` for argument deduction is `int const`. Note that with this change, the `const` that was **not** top-level in the declaration of `rx` became a top-level `const`. Then by §14.8.2.1/2, third bullet point, the `const` is ignored in the type `int const` because it's now a top-level `const`.

To me, this scheme seems to be rather artificial. Thus, I was thinking, why does §5/5 have to be applied to an expression that's being used to deduce a template argument? There must be a stronger reason to justify this rule, that I'm not aware of. That's what I'd like to know. Thanks.

Comment: in c++03 references were indistinguishable as such. that's not quite so in c++11 but still it was a design goal.

Comment: When you're passing by value you're creating a new object, so `const`-ness shouldn't apply in the deduction process.

Comment: I guess this has to do with references being aliases: you can use a reference instead of the original object in almost all cases and get the same behaviour. The one case I know of where it behaves differently is `decltype`.

Comment: Additionally, this deduction scheme guarantees that the parameter is a copy. So you can use inside the function template and be sure that you don't modify the argument that has been passed in. For example, generic algorithms which take iterators tend to recycle the `begin` iterator as an iteration variable.

Comment: Scott Meyers explains this in 23:50 of [Type Deduction and Why You Care](http://vimeo.com/97344493).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the rationale, let's first consider why `const` doesn't make into the argument type deduction:

```
template< class Type >
void foo( Type v ) { v = 0; }

auto main() -> int
{
    int const x = 3;
    foo( x );
}
```

This compiles nicely, mechanistically because C++11 §14.8.2.1/2 third dash says so, “the top level cv-qualifiers of `A`’s type are ignored for type deduction”.

I guess that a large part of the rationale for that is that otherwise various actual argument cv-qualification would produce function template instantiations that are the exact same function *type*, since top level cv-qualifications for formal arguments are ignored wrt. to the type of the function. Such instantiations can be made to have wildly different effects. It would be messy.

Then, regarding why references are dropped, well it they were not then this program,

```
#if defined( USE_REF )
#   define Q &&
    auto kind = "ref";
#else
#   define Q
    auto kind = "non-ref";
#endif

template< class A1, class A2 >
void foo( A1 a1, A2 a2 )
{
    a1 ^= a2;
    a2 ^= a1;
    a1 ^= a2;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    int Q a1 = 111;
    int Q a2 = 222;
    foo( a1, a2 );
    cout << kind << ' ' << a1 << ' ' << a2 << endl;
}
```

would output is numbers in different order depending on `USE_REF`.

But it doesn’t.

And that’s because references are designed so that an `a1` that is a reference to `int`, in C++03 was indistinguishable from an `a1` that directly is an `int`.

---

For a more definitive and informed view of the rationale (the above is very plausible but still just my thoughts about it) it’s *possible* that Bjarne Stroustrup’s “The Design and Evolution of C++” book has something. Or not. Unfortunately I don’t have that book.